"To put the copestone on something", meaning, literary synonyms
The expression "to put the copestone on something" is found in Wuthering Heights", a novel written by Emily Brontë.

On opening the little door, two hairy monsters flew at my throat, bearing me down, and extinguishing the light; while a mingled guffaw from Heathcliff and Hareton put the copestone on my rage and humiliation.

I suspect that it means "to bring to a maximum", but this is bound to be a somewhat crude approximation, if at all correct.
The Merriam-Webster dictionary gives the definition below for "copestone".

Merriam-Webster copestone
1  a stone forming a coping
2  a finishing touch : crown

I'll rely again on Merriam-Webster's dictionary to make precise the term "coping" in the specialized context of architecture, which, if it can be inferred  from the definition that it has an incidence in that field, is for me, and very probably for most people, an unknown.

(Merriam-Webster dictionary) coping : the top or covering layer of a wall that is usually sloped to carry off water

However, "copestone" has acquired a third, very apparently, figurative sense, although the figurativeness is not mentioned in the dictionary that proposes this third sense.

(Dictioanry.com) 3 the crown or completion; finishing touch.

The question is three-fold.

What would be an exact rendering of this expression?

Is its apparent regain in popularity (see ngram below), which I take, without the support of any serious research, as rather the result of a "modern impetus" for literary research (quotes from past literature in recent research papers), and not as a true revival, in fact a reality?




What other likely ways (literary) would seem natural today to express the  same idea?


1- Capstone? 2 - Don't know. 3 - Capstone?

@YosefBaskin I don't get it: there is no such word in my text, and then "copestone" takes on a figurative sense. Do you mean that "capstone" could be substituted for "copestone"?

Sorry. You listed 3 questions and I asked if you thought "capstone" could substitute for "copestone."

@YosefBaskin It seems like a reasonable possibility, but I don't know: I am not familiar with any variant.

Today, we have a keynote speaker. Also core, pinnacle, primo, punchline, da bomb, da shit.

@YosefBaskin In fact, a quick verification shows that there is such a figurative expression ("to put the capstone on something"), but I'd have to study the examples for a long time in order to determine what it means (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put%20the%20capstone%20on%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

A "capstone" can be called a "coping stone". It's just a quaint quirky usage. Whatever - some Americans might think it's the same as to put the cherry on top, or in main mainstream vernacular, to round it off... on top of all that..., to top it all off. Metaphors at this level are transparent to native Anglophones - it's an English Language Learners question.

Is its apparent regain in popularity (see ngram below), which I take, without the support of any serious research, as rather the result of a "modern impetus" for literary reseach (quotes from past literature in recent research papers), and not as a true revival, in fact a reality? Why don't you look at the detailed Google Books results?

@StuartF I just did, and I didn't see any research papers at all on the first page of results for the period between 2015 and 2019.  One was a modern literary work, one was a thesaurus quoting Wuthering Heights to illustrate the word "copestone," and all the others were modern editions of Wuthering Heights.

@StuartF Good question! This is often what I do, but I figure that although I can do that, there are others who can too, and the result to be had that way might be interesting. In fact for the present question there is an answer (below, https://english.stackexchange.com/a/624590/349876) that I couldn't have written myself, and which I find quite instructive. Of course, I will not try to defend myself from the accusation of laziness: I was somewhat lazy (neither would I put forward my argument above as one in defense of laziness).

"a novel due to Emily Brontë" ? Implying "perpetrated by"?

The GoogleNgram is deceptive - the frequency is close to "nil". I suggest you compare the phrase with a reasonably frequent word and see that the use of "copestone" is vanishingly infrequent. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+the+copestone+on%2Ccuriosity&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

@TimR  "Due to" is apparently not idiomatic for authors of books; I've probably been influenced by "theorem due to so and so", which is frequent in mathematical text when it is needed to mention authorship.

As mentioned, 'capstone' is used in the expression nowadays, usually metaphoricallyFrom HiloTutor:

capstone
Like it sounds, a literal capstone is a stone that caps a wall: it's
any of the stones forming the top of a wall or the top of a building.
So, a figurative capstone is any finishing touch or crowning
achievement. In other words, in a series of actions or achievements,
the capstone is the highest, most important one.

Here, it is used ironically, invoking gritted teeth.
The synonymous expression crowning glory ('This was the crowning glory of her academic career') wouldn't work so well used ironically.

A much-studied text will spawn lots of study guides…
The quote is from one of the most popular books in the English language, but more significantly, Wuthering Heights is on the list of set-texts for the UK A-Level examinations in English. That means lots of people are reading it not for pleasure, but to understand it. That leads to questions just like yours.
I suspect the uptick in usage is from a proliferation of online study-guides and revision notes for the text: every one of those documents will contain a note about this word, as it’s not in common English usage (having been supplanted by the soundalike “capstone”). The post-2000 inflection date strongly suggests that this is an Internet-driven phenomenon rather than a resurgence in print or other media, and this fits with the growth in internet-based exam study guides.
Another secondary reason for its popularity is that this passage itself is likely to be used in exam questions, as it forms a key point early in the story, where Lockwood (the narrator) discovers the dark side of his new neighbour, Mr Heathcliff. Those exam questions, as well as sample questions, are now published online.
